Is there a way to dispatch a function with react router and Redux?
I have the following routes:
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: 'new', action: myaction, element: <NewTask /> },
      { path: 'tasks', element: <Tasks /> },
      {
        path: 'task/:id',
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Task /> },
          { path: 'edit', element: <Edit /> },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
])

I need to dispatch some data to Redux store when I click submit on my form.
The problem is that I cannot use useDipatch outside my component named NewTask.
import React from "react"
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom'
import Modal from "../components/Modal"
import Button from '../components/Button'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { hide, show, add } from '../store/store'

const saveEvent = async ({ request }) => {
  const data = await request.formData();

  const dataForm = {
    title: data.get('title'),
    desc: data.get('desc'),
  }

  return null;
}

const NewTask = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const status = useSelector(state => state.modal.show)
  const closeModal = () => dispatch(hide())
  const openModal = () => dispatch(show())

  return <>
    {status && <Modal hide={closeModal}>
      <Button onClick={closeModal} className="btn btn-success"/>
    </Modal>}
    <Form method="post" id="form">
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" className="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="desc" className="form-label">Description</label>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="desc" id="desc" className="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <button type="reset" className="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  </>
}

export { saveEvent }
export default NewTask

I have made some research on internet but nothing is working.

While not a common solution what you could do is import your store instance into your NewTask file and dispatch to the store in the route action.
Example:
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Modal from "../components/Modal";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import { hide, show, add } from "../store/store";
import { store } from "../path/to/store";

const saveEvent = async ({ request }) => {
  const data = await request.formData();

  const dataForm = {
    title: data.get('title'),
    desc: data.get('desc'),
  };

  store.dispatch(someAction(dataForm)); // <-- dispatch action

  return null;
};

...

It doesn't appear you really need the route action here though, it would be more conventional to dispatch the action from the form's submit handler.
Example:
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Modal from "../components/Modal";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import { hide, show, add } from "../store/store";

const NewTask = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const status = useSelector(state => state.modal.show);

  const closeModal = () => dispatch(hide());
  const openModal = () => dispatch(show());

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const title = e.target.title.value;
    const desc = e.target.desc.value;

    const dataForm = {
      title,
      desc,
    };

    dispatch(someAction(dataForm)); // <-- dispatch action
  };

  return (
    <>
      {status && (
        <Modal hide={closeModal}>
          <Button onClick={closeModal} className="btn btn-success" />
        </Modal>
      )}
      <form id="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            id="title"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="desc" className="form-label">Description</label>
          <textarea
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            name="desc"
            id="desc"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <button type="reset" className="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default NewTask;

const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: 'new', element: <NewTask /> },
      { path: 'tasks', element: <Tasks /> },
      {
        path: 'task/:id',
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Task /> },
          { path: 'edit', element: <Edit /> },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
]);

